# Refraction on the edge of mediums

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics

Say I have this setup : [image]

Here a light ray (in red) is incident on the point A in such a way that it is collinear with AB, and the indices of refraction are as mentioned in the figure. So my question is where will the light ray go?

Here is what I thought

- If the ray goes towards the medium with refractive index n3, then as n3 < n2, it will tend to go towards n1.
- But if the ray goes towards n1, then as n1>n2, it will tend to go towards n3.

Therefore, I think that the ray will trace the line segment AB. But then what will happen at the point B??

P.S. Here, ni means the medium with the refractive index as (mu)i

Comment: I meant that I am not sure what would happen, and that I expected tracing the line segment to be the outcome.

Comment: It might be best to consider the case where you aren't along boundaries and then take limits. The problem is at point A you don't have a way to define what medium the light is propagating through.

Comment: But what if I have an experimental setup, where I can vary the angle of incidence at point A in such a way that the refracted ray varies from going to n3 to n1. So what will happen at that transition?

Comment: I didn't think about it. That might be a possibility too, but won't it depend on the relative refractive indices, so that we might have two cases - one where total internal reflection take place, and the other where it doesn't.

Comment: The problem is that for a ray coming in along the boundary in your diagram there isn't a way to define the "incoming" medium and "outgoing" medium. Experimentally, light rays have some finite width, and chances are you won't have the ray exactly in-line.

Comment: @AaronStevens  I get your point, and it was one of the main reasons I wasn't able to get a conclusive answer to this problem. But "what if" this happens somehow ?

Comment: It would be pretty easy to set up an experiment to match the problem, using, for example, glass, water, and air.  I think you would learn a lot from doing the experiment.

Comment: At least one kind of electromagnetic wave can propagate along the interface between two media: a surface plasmon polariton.  See [https://rua.ua.es/dspace/bitstream/10045/75492/1/2018_Zapata-Rodriguez_etal_Dyakonov-Surface-Waves.pdf].

Comment: @S.McGrew thanks for the reference. So it tells with proper explanation that there can be electromagnetic wave along the interface. But what will happen next? Will the general laws of refraction be followed? If yes then how? Or will there be something different?

Comment: Refraction at an interface, in the sense of a change of direction of a light ray, will only occur if the ray is incident at an angle (other than parallel or perperdicular) to the interface.  My understanding is that an electromagnetic "surface wave" along a dielectric interface is analogous to a surface wave at an air/water interface: it stays bound to the interface unless it encounters a structure that directs it away from the interface- like a diffraction grating.  By the way, a grating should be usable to couple light into a surface wave at the interface.

Comment: In this case, then will it continue to keep moving along AB een after crossing the point B, or will it depend on angle ABC?